# Flutter Error: The argument type 'DropdownMenuEntry<DropDownObj>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DropDownOb

Tags: flutter, dart, class, drop-down-menu

What i am trying to do is passing the Drop down menu as list of object that is causing error
The error is occuring in for loop when i am casting the object to the value

{required DropDownObj value}  Type: DropDownObj
the value used to identify the entry.
This value must be unique across all entries in a DropdownMen

this is the MenuList Class

```
class DropDownObj{
  late String label;
  late bool enabled;
  DropDownObj({
    required this.enabled,
    required this.label,
  });
}
```

This is the Menu List that I want to Pass on

```
List<DropdownMenuEntry<DropDownObj>> menuList=[
  DropDownObj(enabled: true, label: "Item1"),
  DropDownObj(enabled: true, label: "Item2"),
  DropDownObj(enabled: true, label: "Item3"),
  DropDownObj(enabled: true, label: "Item4"),
  DropDownObj(enabled: true, label: "Item5"),
].cast<DropdownMenuEntry<DropDownObj>>();
```

The Widget of dropDown Menu

```
class customAutoCompleteDropdown extends StatefulWidget {

  TextEditingController colorController = TextEditingController();
  var onSelected;
  List<DropdownMenuEntry<DropDownObj>> menuEntries = <DropDownObj>[].cast<DropdownMenuEntry<DropDownObj>>();

  customAutoCompleteDropdown({
    Key? key,
    required this.colorController,
    this.onSelected,
    required this.menuEntries,
  }) : super(key: key);



  @override
  State<customAutoCompleteDropdown> createState() => customAutoCompleteDropdownState();
}

class customAutoCompleteDropdownState extends State<customAutoCompleteDropdown> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    for (var element in menuList) {
      widget.menuEntries.add(DropdownMenuEntry<DropDownObj>(
          value: element, // this is where problem is ouccuring
label: element.label, 
enabled: element.enabled,
          style: ButtonStyle(
            foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all( Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer) ,
            backgroundColor:MaterialStateProperty.all( Colors.transparent) ,
            textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer),),
          )

      )
      );
    }

    return DropdownMenu(
      width: 350,
      textStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer
      ),
      menuStyle:  MenuStyle(
        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary),
        surfaceTintColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer),
        // shape:  MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(
        //   side: BorderSide(
        //     color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
        //   ),
        //   borderRadius:  BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0), bottomRight: Radius.circular(10.0)),
        // )
        // )
      ),
      inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
        iconColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
        floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,),
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,),
        outlineBorder:  BorderSide(width: 16.0, color: Colors.lightBlue.shade50),
        enabledBorder:  OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius:const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0),),
          borderSide:  BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary, width: 0.0),
        ),
        focusedBorder:  OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius:const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0),),
          borderSide:  BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary, width: 1.0),
        ),
        disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius:const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0),),
          borderSide:  BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary, width: 1.0),
        ),
        errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0),),
          borderSide:  BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error, width: 0.0),
        ),
        focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0),),
          borderSide:  BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error, width: 1.0),
        ),

      ),
      label: const Text('DropDown Menu'),
      dropdownMenuEntries: widget.menuEntries,
      onSelected:  (value)=>setState(() {
        print(value);
      }),

    );
  }
}
```

The Page that is loading that Widget

```
class formsPage extends StatefulWidget {

  const formsPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<formsPage> createState() => formsPageState();
}

class formsPageState extends State<formsPage> {

  IconLabel? selectedIcon;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    late  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();


    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
        cursorColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary, 
        selectionColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
        selectionHandleColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,

      )),
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
                  customAutoCompleteDropdown(
                    colorController:_controller,
                    onSelected:"hh",
                    menuEntries:menuList,
                  )

                ],

              ),
            )

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to cast on list, you can do

```dart
 List<DropDownObj> menuList = [
    DropDownObj(enabled: true, label: "Item1"),
    DropDownObj(enabled: true, label: "Item2"),
    DropDownObj(enabled: true, label: "Item3"),
    DropDownObj(enabled: true, label: "Item4"),
    DropDownObj(enabled: true, label: "Item5"),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    for (var element in menuList) {
      widget.menuEntries.add(DropdownMenuEntry<DropDownObj>(
        value: element,
        label: element.label,
        enabled: element.enabled,
      ));
    }
```

Simplify like

```dart
class customAutoCompleteDropdown extends StatefulWidget {
  TextEditingController colorController = TextEditingController();
  var onSelected;
  List<DropDownObj> menuEntries = [];

  customAutoCompleteDropdown({
    Key? key,
    required this.colorController,
    this.onSelected,
    required this.menuEntries,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<customAutoCompleteDropdown> createState() =>
      customAutoCompleteDropdownState();
}

class customAutoCompleteDropdownState
    extends State<customAutoCompleteDropdown> {
  List<DropDownObj> menuList = [
    DropDownObj(enabled: true, label: "Item1"),
    DropDownObj(enabled: true, label: "Item2"),
    DropDownObj(enabled: true, label: "Item3"),
    DropDownObj(enabled: true, label: "Item4"),
    DropDownObj(enabled: true, label: "Item5"),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    widget.menuEntries.addAll(menuList);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownMenu(
      width: 350,
      textStyle:
          TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer),
      label: const Text('DropDown Menu'),
      dropdownMenuEntries: widget.menuEntries
          .map(
            (e) => DropdownMenuEntry(
              label: e.label,
              value: e.label,
              enabled: e.enabled,
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
      onSelected: (value) => setState(() {
        print(value);
      }),
    );
  }
}

/// 

class formsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const formsPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<formsPage> createState() => formsPageState();
}

class formsPageState extends State<formsPage> {
  var selectedIcon;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    late TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
    List<DropDownObj> menuList = [
      DropDownObj(enabled: true, label: "Item1"),
      DropDownObj(enabled: true, label: "Item2"),
      DropDownObj(enabled: true, label: "Item3"),
      DropDownObj(enabled: true, label: "Item4"),
      DropDownObj(enabled: true, label: "Item5"),
    ];
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
        cursorColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
        selectionColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
        selectionHandleColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
      )),
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              customAutoCompleteDropdown(
                colorController: _controller,
                onSelected: "hh",
                menuEntries: menuList,
              )
            ],
          ),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `customAutoCompleteDropdown(colorController:_controller,onSelected:"hh",
               menuEntries:menuList,// now Problem Occurs here
  )`

Comment: The argument type 'List<DropDownObj>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<DropdownMenuEntry<DropDownObj>>'

Comment: When i am calling the Custom Widget

Comment: My proposal is to simply use `List<DropDownObj>` and only transform to dropdownmenuEntry on dropdownButton/